# NoClassDefFoundError while trying to connect Java to Mongodb Atlas

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, intellij-idea, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB atlas using Java and I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/connection/StreamFactoryHelper
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.getStreamFactory(MongoClientImpl.java:235)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.createCluster(MongoClientImpl.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl.<init>(MongoClientImpl.java:73)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:108)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:61)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.internal.connection.StreamFactoryHelper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more
```

Here's my code:

```
package org.example;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://kkartik:<password>@agilecluster.8wtmt68.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("SampleDB");

        MongoCollection col = db.getCollection("sampleCollection");
    }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml dependancy:

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
                <version>4.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See if it helps to add "mongo-java-driver" dependency to your pom.xml. See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/#mongodb-driver

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work. It returns this error when I try inserting it:
"Dependency 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.14' not found"

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It returns the same error.